# problem in adding uiactivity indicator in uitableview controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

Hi i am not able to add uiactivity indicator in uitableview controller, can someone help me out

I am having a table view controller now on click event of  cell in table i want to display activity indicator  because on click event of cell it takes 3 to 4 second of processing , so i want to display activity indicator at that time but when i drag and drop activity indicator on  tableview controller it does allow me to add that 
so i am confused how to add that activity indicator

thansk in advance..

Comment: no-one can help you out because that's not a real question... what EXACTLY are you trying to achieve? What code have you already tried? What does the class do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you add it programatically in your cell's accesory view?

Comment: no its not on each cell it is like that whenever user clicks on any cell i just wanted to display activity indicator at the centre of my table view contoller and not in each cell ...

Comment: Then I think you should add a transparent UIView to the tableview with the activity indicator in the middle. That should be quite straightforward.

Comment: ya i was thinking of that only anyways thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];

activityIndicator.center = yourTableView.center;

[activityIndicator startAnimating];

[yourTableView addSubview: activityIndicator];
```

top stop it simply use

```
[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
activityIndicator = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have it wired up properly to the controller class in IB?  Where are you trying to display it?  How are you doing it in the code?  These are things that would be helpful to know...

Comment: For some reason I can't comment on the answer below.  This goes with that:  Why don't you overlay a view on top of the table and make it hidden until the user clicks a cell.  Then reveal it with an activity indicator.  Or maybe you could put one in a toolbar or something.  That's also a nice alternative.